# Regex for adding CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am trying to add and remove class using the following script  to #menuElem tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#menuElem li ul').each(function (){
  $(this).addClass("fallback browse-experience-drop-down-width");
});
$('#menuElem li a').each(function (){
  $(this).addClass("skew");
});
 $('#menuElem li ul li a').each(function (){
  $(this).removeClass("skew");
});
</script>
```

Ideally this should work, but not working, Is it possible to with regex replace?

See below the HTML that we are adding the class, you can find menuElem inside the HTML

```
<!-- Header zone -->
<!-- header -->
<div class="tenantHeade fs-headerfooter-widget">
<!---->
<header>
<div id="container" class="container">
<div class="logocont"><a href="/" class="logo">website</a></div>
<!-- Mobile nav btn -->
<a class="nav-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ada-compliant visible-xs"></span></a>
<!-- Mobile user options (for anon and preferred visitors) -->

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="member-toggle">
<span class="ada-compliant visible-xs"></span>

</a>

<!-- Main nav -->
<nav class="main-nav inactive">
 <ul id="menuElem">
  <li>
   <a href="https://www.website.com/FareFinder/DeepLinkSearch/?SearchFrom=browseexperiences&amp;TravlePeriod=12&amp;AdultCount=2"><span class="antiskew">Browse Experiences</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="https://www.website.com/FareFinder/DeepLinkSearch/?SearchFrom=website&amp;amp;TravlePeriod=12&amp;amp;AdultCount=2">website</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="https://www.website.com/local">Local</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="https://www.website.com/https://www.website.com/FareFinder/DeepLinkSearch/?SearchFromType=theme&amp;SearchFrom=voluntours&amp;TravlePeriod=12&amp;Keyword=voluntours&amp;AdultCount=2">Voluntours</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="https://www.website.com/https://www.website.com/FareFinder/DeepLinkSearch/?SearchFromType=theme&amp;SearchFrom=welcomewebsite&amp;TravlePeriod=12&amp;Keyword=welcome+website&amp;AdultCount=2">Welcome website</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="https://www.website.com/Marketing/becomemember"><span class="antiskew">Become a Member</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="https://www.website.com/Marketing/becomemember"><span class="antiskew">Daily Deals</span></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Why [tag:regex] and no [tag:jquery]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop when using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#menuElem > li > ul').addClass("fallback browse-experience-drop-down-width");
$('#menuElem > li > a').addClass("skew");
$('#menuElem > li > ul > li > a').removeClass("skew");
</script>
```

Also, you should use the > sign to indicate direct children, then you probably don't need the removeClass line